# Почему не могу собрать deb-пакет?

Tags: linux, debian, deb

собирается нормально, но при установке:

```
sudo dpkg -i ./adfi.deb
dpkg: ошибка при обработке архива ./adfi.deb (--install):
 не удалось открыть файл «/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci//usr»: Это каталог
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 ./adfi.deb
```

Структура папок:

```
--adfi
----DEBIAN
------usr
--------bin
----------adfi1
----------try.expect
----control
```

Файл control:

```
Package: adfi
Version: 1.0
Section: utils
Priority: optional
Architecture: all
Depends: telnet, nmap, expect
Maintainer: Voropaev Dmitriy <voropaevdmtr@gmail.com>
Description: ADFI - Utility to search the network for devices using standard login / password for telnet access.
```

Собираю так:

```
***$ dpkg-deb --build ./adfi
dpkg-deb: building package 'adfi' in './adfi.deb'.
```

Comment: что это за «структура каталогов»? каталога `adfi`, который вы передаёте параметром программе *dpkg-deb*? распакуйте любой файл с пакетом (`$ dpkg-deb -R файл.deb каталог`) и сравните с тем, что у вас.